# separate div to 3 columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I asked same question 2 days ago but now i still don't get it. 
I have 1 div and i want it to be separate into 3 columns of div. I know how to do this for 2 column but, when i am trying 3 column(right, center and left) i get this:

[image]

**Problem:** The pink square is not in the center

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="our_services" class="container">
    <h1>המוצרים שלנו</h1>
    <div id="try">
        <div id="product1">
        </div>
        <div id="product2">
        </div>
        <div id="product3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#our_services {
    /*height: 450px;*/
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "open_sans_hebrewregular", "alefregular",arial,"Times New Roman";
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(224,224,224);
    overflow: auto;
    margin: auto;
}

#try {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}

#product1 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 75%;
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px;
}

#product2 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 75%;
    background-color: pink;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px;
}

#product3 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 75%;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: can you post your code in http://jsfiddle.net/, its help us to understand the problem

Comment: Rule is, to put all these divs as Float left and specify , width 33% will work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `display:inline-block;` instead.
[exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/1gqxs307/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
#our_services {

  /*height: 450px;*/

  text-align: center;

  font-family: "open_sans_hebrewregular", "alefregular", arial, "Times New Roman";

  color: black;

  background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224);

  overflow: auto;

  margin: auto;

}

#try {

  background-color: orange;

  width: 50%;

  height: 50%;

  margin: auto;

}

#product1 {

  width: 30%;

  height: 75%;

  background-color: green;

  float: left;

  margin: 1.5%;

}

#product2 {

  width: 30%;

  height: 75%;

  background-color: pink;

  float: left;

  margin: 1.5%;

}

#product3 {

  width: 30%;

  height: 75%;

  background-color: blue;

  float: left;

  margin: 1.5%;

}
```

```html
<div id="our_services" class="container">
  <h1>המוצרים שלנו</h1>
  <div id="try">
    <div id="product1">
      afs
    </div>
    <div id="product2">
      asf
    </div>
    <div id="product3">
      asf
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You had float right as well on one of the boxes

Answer (score 0):

use float left to 1st and 2nd div also. and give margin on percentage. I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand:
If you don't want any spaces between you'd have to set the `width` property to `(100/3)%`

It all depends on your layout of what you want, if you want margin spaces between them all so that they're equally spaced between each other and the edges of their container div you'll have to work out what to do there.  So in the case now you have `30%` width for each, that leaves you with `10%` spacing width which you can spread to `2.5%` for `margin-left:` of your first 2 divs and then for the 3rd div use `2.5%` for `margin-right:` (for a space between the right side and the 3rd div) `margin-left:`

But as I said, it all depends on what exactly you want for your layout, so if this doesn't answer your question could you tell me more about your expected layout?

If you want a very simple fix based off of what you have at the moment you could set the `margin:` property to `auto` and that should center the middle div between what you have now.

Edit:  You should also edit the float properties so that they all float one way.

Comment: Removing the float properties will screw up the layout. Just saying.

Comment: Would it?  Well I do agree with your answer with making all the floats float the same way because that wouldn't cause any issues...

Comment: Ye, if you don't have float they will stack up one under the other.

Comment: Oh yeah, let me edit my answer...  Can't believe I forgot about that!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way you can do this purely with html/css techniques. You can arrange the items with javascript after the dom (or this part at least) has loaded.

On the other hand, this gets you a little closer to what you want, although the distances between rows won't be equal to the distances between firs/last row and beginning/end of the orange rectangle:

```
 <div id="our_services" class="container">
<h1>המוצרים שלנו</h1>
<div id="try">
    <div class="smth">
        <div id="product1" class="product">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="smth">
        <div id="product2" class="product">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="smth">
        <div id="product3" class="product">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
#our_services{
/*height: 450px;*/
text-align: center;
font-family:"open_sans_hebrewregular", "alefregular",arial,"Times New Roman";
color: black;
background-color: rgb(224,224,224);
overflow: auto;
margin: auto;
}

.smth {
    width: 33%;
    height: 75%;
    float: left;    
}

#try{
    background-color:orange;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    margin:auto;
}

.product {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

#product1{
    background-color:green;
}

#product2{
    background-color:pink;
}

#product3{
    background-color:blue;
}

</style>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the **example** below:

**Code:**

```css
#our_services {          
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "open_sans_hebrewregular", "alefregular", arial, "Times New Roman";
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
#try {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
#product1 {
  width: 31%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
}
#product2 {
  width: 31%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
}
#product3 {
  width: 31%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div id="our_services" class="container">
  <h1>המוצרים שלנו</h1>
  <div id="try">
    <div id="product1">
    </div>
    <div id="product2">
    </div>
    <div id="product3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/biplobice/uwjruxwf/)

Answer (score 0):

add the following css:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and add the following properties to `#our_services` css:

```
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
```

further set `box-sizing: border-box;` and `margin: 0% 0% 0% 2.5%;` (top as you need, right 0%, bottom as you need and left 2.5%) for the prouctu divs. Btw. you should extract common style to a `product` class and apply the class on the product divs...

Answer (score 0):

One nice solution is to use `display:table` and `display:table-cell`. Which will works for 2 and 3 div both.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="our_services" class="container">
<h1>המוצרים שלנו</h1>
<div id="try">
<div id="product1" class="product">
</div>
<div id="product2" class="product">
</div>
<div id="product3" class="product">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #our_services {
    background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
    color: black;
    font-family: "open_sans_hebrewregular","alefregular",arial,"Times New Roman";
    height: 450px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#try {
    background-color: orange;
    display: table;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
     border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
.product{
     display: table-cell;
    height: 75%;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 30%;
}

#product1 {
    background-color: green;
}
#product2 {
    background-color: pink;  
}
#product3 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Check [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/LqhopL6z/2/)